# Solving a functional equation with dynamic programming (Preparation for mathematics competition)

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations, dynamic-programming

This question is based a bit on an "Ansatz" but I hope my intuition is right.
I was practising functional equations for a mathematics competition and I encountered the following equation:

$f(xy) = yf(x) + x + f(f(y) − f(x))$

After substituting for $x=1$, I get:

$f(n) = nf(1) + f(f(n)-f(1))$

which looks a lot like Cauchy's equation. I was wondering whether you could solve this using dynamic programming, after all

$f(n)-f(1) = \textbf{(n-1)}f(1)+ f(f(n)-f(1))$

In the likely case that my hunch is wrong, it would be great if you could show me how to solve this equation (or give me hints) and tell me when dynamic programming is appropriate.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286833/finding-all-functions-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-which-satisfy-fxy-yfxxf-b/4287755#4287755

Comment: There is also this: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2220859p16882029

Comment: @SaiMehta Ok thanks but what about the possibility of using dynamic programming?